# Active flag for over 5 days (and counting) on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight

I submitted a custom-reason flag on an answer on *"Aug 30 at 11:42"*, and it is still labeled **active**. I also have another custom-reason flag on another answer on a different question from *"Aug 30 at 13:04"* that is labeled **active**.

Why is this? Has my flag weight changed, or are moderators responding slower than usual to custom-reason flags?

Comment: There's about 3000 flags every four hours, so maybe it just takes time to get through them all

Comment: I have two flags that have been open since August 29th. My solution to that (and to a couple that were declined that I totally disagree with) is to not worry about them and move on to other questions. Flag weight isn't used any longer, so there's no impact if they stay open.

Comment: @KenWhite Flag weight does exist, and it is used, it's just no longer visible to users directly, it is just silently used to help sort the items in the queue.

Comment: @Servy: I stand corrected. I could have sworn I saw a post over the last weekend that said it wasn't, but I couldn't find it to include in my comment. Still not worth being concerned over a single flag that stays open a few days though, IMO. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite People say that you shouldn't care about it all the time, because you shouldn't, you should just flag what you feel is appropriate, and ensure you don't intentionally abuse the system.  It's still an important tool for those that *do* abuse the system though.

Comment: @Servy: Agreed. I flag those (with an "other" category and an explanation) frequently, and if there is still a flag weight mine is pretty good, I think. :-)

Comment: @Servy - actually, it isn't used anymore... we even dropped the DB field.